# How to capture Datawindow move event?

Tags: events, controls, move, powerbuilder

My Datawindow has title with it and user can drag it inside main window anywhere.

I need to move other controls away in the main window to make room for new position for the Datawindow control at runtime.

I dont want to do it with mousemove or drag events because that will increase my code like grass.

Simple move of the control should have a way somehow.

How do i capture the move event for the datawindow control?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom event on the datawindow mapped to pbm_dwnmousemove. Within your new event you would have to check to see if the datawindow is moving on top of the other controls and then re-position them as appropriate.

Comment: Things to consider:
|1- both events work the same way
|2- there are some other controls too in the main window
|3- move of a control and the move of mouse are different events (my guess)
|4- In main window i drag datawindow control from its title bar by holding down mouse left button
|5- i do not want to write code for mouse move event in every existing control in the main window.
|6- mouse pointer when hit border of some other control in the main window mouse move event stops right there.